# How to get both the full path and the name without extension of a file?

Tags: c#

How do I get both the full path and the name(without the extension) of each file in an array. My code is like

```
string myPath=@"D:\Practice\2017";
DirectoryInfo myPathInfo = new DirectoryInfo(myPath);
FileInfo[] myXmlFiles = myPathInfo.GetFiles("*.xml",SearchOption.AllDirectories);
    foreach (FileInfo xmlFile in myXmlFiles)
    {
        var xmlName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(xmlFile.Name);
        var xmlLoc=Path.GetFullPath(xmlFile.Name);
    }
```

I get the `xmlName` as desired but get null in `xmlLoc`.
How do I fix this?

Comment: What is the value of `xmlFile.Name`?

Comment: `FileInfo` has a `DirectoryName` property looking at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo(v=vs.110).aspx . I suspect it does what you want (though I'm not 100% sure).

Comment: @Chris does `DirectoryName` give the full path of the file?

Comment: @Don_B Read the documentation!

Comment: Try using the debugger & examine xmlFile.

Comment: @Don_B: There were links to the documentation in my comment. Follow it. Read it. If needs be experiment with test code to see what is returned.

Comment: Why not use xmlFile.FullName?

Comment: You have to remove the extension :  xmlFile.SubString(0, xmlFile.LastIndoexOf("."))

Comment: @jdweng that's not how you should remove the extension. use `Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension`. your method fails when the file didn't have an extension to begin with

Comment: The test for a period before using SubString() method.

Answer (score 1):

`Path.GetFullPath` depends on the application context, and so passing in just a file name will result in some confusion:

> This method uses current directory and current volume information to fully qualify path. **If you specify a file name only in path, GetFullPath returns the fully qualified path of the current directory**.

To get the original path of the XML file from the `FileInfo` object use the `.FullName` property:

```
foreach (FileInfo xmlFile in myXmlFiles)
{
  var xmlName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(xmlFile.Name);
  var xmlLoc= xmlFile.FullName;
}
```

`xmlLoc` will now contain the full path of the XML file: `D:\Practice\2017\someXml.xml`

Answer (score 0):

Make use of `DirectoryName` property of `FileInfo` class. You might also require `Path.Combine` since the above property does not give you completely what you want, but a part of it. Put together the required code using these properties.